# The probability of horse A winning a race is $\frac 13$ and that of B is $\frac 15$

Tags: probability

> The probability of horse A winning a race is $\frac 13$ and that of B is $\frac 15$. Find the probability that either of them will win

The two cases are where A wins and B loses and A loses and B wins

That gives
$$\frac {4}{15} + \frac{2}{15}$$
$$=0.4$$

But given ans is $0.533$

Where am I going wrong

Comment: Your fractions are wrong.  $\frac 5{15}+\frac 3{15}=\frac 8{15}=.53\cdots$.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore but in this situation (a single race) $A\cap B$ (both horses win) cannot happen, I guess.

Comment: @TitoEliatron oh god what an error i made

Answer (score 4):

The two events are mutually exclusive. For mutually exclusive events $A$ and $B$, the probability that $A$ or $B$ will occur is the sum of the probabilities $P[A]+P[B]$. Just add $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}=0533..$

Comment: Hey, wait, the chance that either of them will win should be $1$, because it is the only possible when the $2$ horses are competing.

Comment: @BookOfFlames there may be more horses ,nothing is said about that

Comment: Doesn’t one horse winning imply the other one is not wrong? How are they exclusive events then?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, that is what mutually exclusive means. If $A$ happens, then $B$ cannot happen and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the probabilities:

- $\frac{1}{3}$ A wins, $\frac{2}{3}$ A loses.
- $\frac{1}{5}$ B wins, $\frac{4}{5}$ B loses.

But notice how, since these event are EXCLUSIVE (that means that $A$ winning implies $B$ not winning, to be said, being $\frac{1}{3}$ is equal to $P$[$A$ wins $\cap$ $B$ loses]), you don't have to multiply them, so you just sum them up, obtaining:
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}=\boxed{\frac{8}{15} =0.5\bar{3}}$$